# Decode hexadecimal NCRs in Java

Tags: java, html, escaping, decode

I want to decode the following Strings I got from a HTTP GET request from a website, using Java:

- `&#xd6;`
- `&#039;`
- `&#xfc;`

(I actually have to put them into code blogs, Stackoverflow automatically decodes them, I hope I can do it too soon ;) )

these equal (which I want to be decoded)

- Ö
- '
- ü

How can I decode them? I tried the Apache Commons lang:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(string);
```

and it can convert `&#039;` but not the other ones (german special chars).

Do you have an idea? I found online decoders for it (like http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/), but I cannot find any functions that's working...

Comment: Unfortunately "decode" has several meanings.  What output do you want?  Are you trying to display the corresponding characters?  In what environment?  Try assuming that we don't know where you are or what you're trying to do when we read the question...

Comment: I want to decode the strings in the first list to the character in the second list (Ö, ', ü). I am using Java and got it from a HTTP GET request. Updated my question. Hope you can understand me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it is not working. My java files where not saved as UTF-8 encoded. To set this in eclipse you have to go to 
**General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding -> Other** and select **UTF-8**

[image: Settings of text encoding]

After this, the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for that:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
...
String parsed = Jsoup.parse("&#xd6;&#039;&#xfc;").text();
System.out.print(parsed);  // prints Ö'ü
```

Comment: Oh wow... the .java file was not saved as UTF-8, eclipse wanted me to save it as UTF-8. After that, all my solutions I tried are working :S and you solutions works of course too. Thanks :)

Comment: That is why I'm always keeping my sources in UTF-8) Glad you have it resolved anyway